# Codeigniter controller in subfolder extends outside one

Tags: codeigniter, controller, hierarchy, subdirectory, require-once

Is it possible a controller inside a subfolder, lets call it 'category', extends from a controller from the parent folder?

Example:

- application_controller.php in the controller folder
- category in the folder controller/category

It keeps me showing the error

```
require_once(../application_controller.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Is there some trick i'm missing to do that?

Thanks in advance
Elkas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're technically executing in a wierd scope because of how the controllers are loaded up.

```
require_once(APPPATH.'controllers/application_controller.php');
```

This is what you're looking for.

`APPPATH` will always point to your `application/` folder.